# Рассчет ответа при нажатии на кнопку ajax-запросом

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, html

Делаю калькулятор, хотелось бы при нажатии на кнопку рассчитать ответ, появился без перезагрузки с помощью в ajax, подскажите, в чем ошибка, заранее благодарен. Вот скрипты:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formcalc").click(function runajax() {
        var facture = $("facture").val();
        var ploshad = $("ploshad").val();
        var kolUglov = $("kolUglov").val();
        var decorLenta = $("decorLenta").val();
        var karniz = $("karniz").val();
        var svet = $("svet").val();
        var ventil = $("ventil").val();
        var obhodTrub = $("obhodTrub").val();
        var send = $("send").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "facture=" + facture,
            "ploshad=" + ploshad,
            "kolUglov=" + kolUglov,
            "decorLenta=" + decorLenta,
            "karniz=" + karniz,
            "svet=" + svet,
            "ventil=" + ventil,
            "send=" + send,
            "obhodTrub=" + obhodTrub,
            url: "formcalc.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {

                var temp = data.summ;
                $("#resultCalc").text(temp);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

А вот форма хтмл:

```
<fieldset>
            <legend><strong>Предварительный расчет стоимости натяжного потолка</strong></legend>
            <p><label for="ploshad" class="bold">Площадь потока, м2:  </label></p>
                <p><input class="input" type="text" name="ploshad" id="ploshad" size="30" maxlength="20"></p>
            <p><label for="facture" class="bold">Фактура:  </label></p>
                <select name="facture" id="facture">
<?
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT id, nameFacture FROM facture", $db);
if (!$result1) {
    echo "<p>Отправьте код ошибки на данную почту noviigorod_sbk@mail.ru:</p>";
    exit(mysql_error());
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result1) > 0) {
    $myrow1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);

    do {
        printf("<option value='%s' >%s</option>", $myrow1["id"], $myrow1["nameFacture"]);
    } while ($myrow1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1));
} else {
    echo "<p>Площадь равен нолю</p>";

    exit();
}
?>
                </select>
<?
do
    printf("<p><label for='%s' class='bold'>%s:  </label></p>
                <p><input class='input' type='text' name='%s' id='%s' size='30'></p>
                <div class='miniText'>%s</div>", $myrow2["elements"], $myrow2["title"], $myrow2["elements"], $myrow2["elements"], $myrow2["ps"]); while ($myrow2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2));
?>

            <p><input type="button" value="Рассчитать" name="send" id="send"></p> 
            <fieldset> <div>ИТОГОВАЯ СТОИМОСТЬ ПОТОЛКА: </div><p id="resultCalc"></p></fieldset>
```

А вот сервер обработки:

```
<?php

include("../blocks/bd.php");

if (isset($_POST['facture'])) {
    $facture = $_POST['facture'];
}
if (isset($_POST['ploshad'])) {
    $ploshad1 = $_POST['ploshad'];
}

if (isset($_POST['kolUglov'])) {
    $kolUglov = $_POST['kolUglov'];
}
if (isset($_POST['decorLenta'])) {
    $decorLenta = $_POST['decorLenta'];
}
if (isset($_POST['karniz'])) {
    $karniz = $_POST['karniz'];
}
if (isset($_POST['svet'])) {
    $svet = $_POST['svet'];
}
if (isset($_POST['lustra'])) {
    $lustra = $_POST['lustra'];
}
if (isset($_POST['ventil'])) {
    $ventil = $_POST['ventil'];
}
if (isset($_POST['obhodTrub'])) {
    $obhodTrub = $_POST['obhodTrub'];
}
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    $send = $_POST['send'];
}

if (isset($ploshad1)) {
    $q            = mysql_query("SELECT do_10, ot_10_do_15, ot_15_do_20, ot_20 FROM facture WHERE id='$facture'", $db);
    $priceFacture = mysql_fetch_array($q);
}

if (($ploshad1) > 0 || ($ploshad1) < 10) {
    $pr = ($ploshad1 * $priceFacture['do_10']);
}
if (($ploshad1) > 10 || ($ploshad1) < 15) {
    $pr = ($ploshad1 * $priceFacture['ot_10_do_15']);
}
if (($ploshad1) > 15 || ($ploshad1) < 20) {
    $pr = ($ploshad1 * $priceFacture['ot_15_do_20']);
}
if (($ploshad1) > 20) {
    $pr = ($ploshad1 * $priceFacture['ot_20']);
}

$a           = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM calculator WHERE elements='kolUglov'", $db);
$priceUglov  = mysql_fetch_array($a);
$b           = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM calculator WHERE elements='decorLenta'", $db);
$priceLenta  = mysql_fetch_array($b);
$c           = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM calculator WHERE elements='karniz'", $db);
$priceKarniz = mysql_fetch_array($c);
$d           = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM calculator WHERE elements='svet'", $db);
$priceSvet   = mysql_fetch_array($d);
$e           = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM calculator WHERE elements='lustra'", $db);
$priceLustra = mysql_fetch_array($e);
$j           = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM calculator WHERE elements='ventil'", $db);
$priceVentil = mysql_fetch_array($j);
$k           = mysql_query("SELECT price FROM calculator WHERE elements='obhodTrub'", $db);
$priceTrub   = mysql_fetch_array($k);

$summ = $pr + ($kolUglov * $priceUglov['price']) + ($decorLenta * $priceLenta['price']) + ($karniz * $priceKarniz['price']) + ($svet * $priceSvet['price']) + ($lustra * $priceLustra['price']) + ($ventil * $priceVentil['price']) + ($obhodTrub * $priceTrub['price']);

echo json_encode($summ);
?>
```

Comment: @bemulima, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Вы сами то в этой каше разберетесь сходу?

Comment: Бравоо!!!) Спасибо всем, код афигительный! Работает, все дело в php был:) изменил конец на $summ['key'] = $summ1;
        echo  json_encode ($summ) ;
Респект вам!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#send").click(function(){
        var data={
          facture: $("#facture").val(),
          ploshad: $("#ploshad").val(),
          kolUglov: $("#kolUglov").val(),
          decorLenta: $("#decorLenta").val(),
          karniz: $("#karniz").val(),
          svet: $("#svet").val(),
          ventil: $("#ventil").val(),
          obhodTrub: $("#obhodTrub").val(),
          send: $("#send").val()
        }
        $.ajax({type: "POST", url: "formcalc.php", data: data, dataType: 'json', success: function(data){
            $("#resultCalc").text(data.summ);
        }});
        return false;
      });
    });
```

У вас не правильно собиралась строка в data: и привязка клика неизвестно к чему была.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, попробовал не получилось(

Comment: какие ошибки выдает ?

Comment: На каком этапе ошибка? Отправляется ли аякс? Что он отправляет? Приходит ли ответ? Что в ответе?

Comment: никаких действии, при нажатии кнопки, пытаюсь найти), но пока без результатно

Comment: а что firebug говорит?

Comment: сделайте банальный alert(1) при старте, а у $.ajax есть метод beforeSend

Comment: >никаких действии, при нажатии кнопки

При нажатии кнопки "Рассчитать"? Вы поправили привязку функции у себя ($("#send").click() вместо $("#formcalc").click())?

Comment: да поправил, честно говоря я даже скопировал ваш код и вставил

Comment: Обратите внимание на комментарий @Tolbase, добавьте алерт в начале функции клика и посмотрите, вызывается ли она.

$("#send").click(function(){ alert('Вызывается') })

Comment: dataType: 'text'

echo json_encode($summ); -> echo $summ;

var temp = data.summ;
$("#resultCalc").text(temp);    ->  $("#resultCalc").text(data);

Answer (score 3):

Первое, что увидел, и надо бы заменить это:

```
data: "facture=" + facture, "ploshad=" + ploshad...
```

на:

```
data: ({
facture:facture,
ploshad:ploshad,
...
})
```

Comment: alert работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте знак **&** добавить

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "facture=" + facture,
        "&ploshad=" + ploshad,
        "&kolUglov=" + kolUglov,
        "&decorLenta=" + decorLenta,
        "&karniz=" + karniz,
        "&svet=" + svet,
        "&ventil=" + ventil,
        "&send=" + send,
        "&obhodTrub=" + obhodTrub,
```

Comment: И убрать запятые после каждого значения. Тогда должно работать.

Comment: Смысл этого? Вы просто соберете строку, вместо объекта - эффект будет тот же. Тут либо не отправляется аякс, либо он корректно не обрабатывается сервером, либо не возвращает нужные данные. Мы все тычем пальцем в небо ибо информации по отладке у нас никакой :(